# Way to bulk update (with unique values) in Django

Tags: python, django, sql-update

Let's say I have a list of dicts with emails and birthdays:

```
p = [\
    {'email': 'someone@somewhere.com', 'birthday': '1990-01-01'},
    {'email': 'someone_else@somewhereelse.com', 'birthday': '1980-02-05'},
    #...etc
]
```

I want to update the `People` objects in the database. The raw sql would normally have as many queries as `len(p)`, so this makes me think of doing:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
for person in p:
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            People.objects.filter(email=person['email']).update(birthday=person['birthday'])
    except IntegrityError:
        #handle the exception
```

I'm not experienced enough in Django to know if this is good practice though. What's the most pythonic way to express what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do all these email ids already exists in the database? Could there be multiple entries in `People` table for same email id?

Comment: I suppose it would be good practice to check on update, but there shouldn't be duplicates; this is already verified on insertion. In the above code, any `People` that have the same email get the same birthday.

Comment: For better code you could write `with transaction.atomic():` outside your for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you filter and update, the same update will be applied to all the filtered entries. Django doesn't provide a bulk update operation where you can update different values on different entries.

You can make your code better by including the `for` loop inside the `transaction.atomic()` block instead of having the atomic block for each entry in the for loop:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    for person in p:
        try:              
            People.objects.filter(email=person['email']).update(birthday=person['birthday'])
        except IntegrityError:
            #handle the exception
```

Comment: Note that this answer is now out of date. Django 2.2 and up  supports bulk_update() method natively, similar to one provided by django-bulk-update, without needing any third party libraries.

Comment: ^^^relevant link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Comment: But this solution is still better than `bulk_update`, because it doesn't `SELECT` records one by one...

Answer (score 6):

Using Django's `bulk_update` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

```python
objs = []
for person in p:
    obj = People.objects.get(email=person['email'])
    obj.birthday = person['birthday']
    objs.append(obj)
People.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['birthday'], batch_size=1000)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a library: [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update).

```
people = Person.objects.all()
for person in people:
  person.name = random.choice(random_names)

bulk_update(people, update_fields=['name']) 
# or 
Person.objects.bulk_update(people, update_fields=['name'])
```